# media query issues

Tags: iphone, html, css, media-queries

I'm working on a website and I'm trying to format it properly to also work on an iPhone.  When you visit the page on an iPhone, it does what the media query says however everything is really small.  It doesn't zoom in like I expected it would.  I want the website to take up the whole screen on the phone.

An image is attached to this and a link to my website is: http://vacavall.mysite.syr.edu/weather_rc

here's a link to see what it looks like on an iPhone:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/yspa45cl923q4wg/IMG952876.jpg

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the viewport to use the device's width as opposed to its default. Drop the following into your `<head>` and see if this resolves the issue:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Read further in the [Safari Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html).

Comment: great!  thanks!  what exactly is the "viewport" for.  I've never used it before

Comment: @user1350204 Your viewport is the framed region on your device. By default your iPhone tries to squeeze over 900 pixels into a 320 pixel region, which is why your page appears *zoomed out*. We're telling it to respect the device's width instead.